# How much treasure is missing from the Keep on the Shadowfell?

Tags: dnd-4e, published-adventures, treasure

According to comments [here](http://elevenfootpole.blogspot.com/2009/08/treasure-parcels.html), as well as the feelings of both my players and I, Keep on the Shadowfell does not award nearly as much treasure as the 4e parcel system suggests that it should.

Does anyone know how much is actually missing?

Comment: Could you define H/P/E and expand the question to include these terms? We want this stuff to be Googlable, right?

Comment: And as they're completely different published adventures, shouldn't this be 3 different questions?

Comment: Please break this down. If you don't want to explain H/P/E I'm sure some kind editor will come by and clean it up.

Comment: @Brian: 9 actually, each tier has 3 modules.

Comment: Asking 'how much treasure is missing' is assuming that indeed, treasure is missing. More correct would be to ask "Is treasure missing from the Heroic/Paragon/Epic official 4E modules?"

Comment: @Adriano Well, "none" could be a viable answer to the question. :)

Comment: Yes, but it's a leading question in any case.

Comment: Edited the question based on the feedback provided here. Does it help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's take the example of Keep on the Shadowfell. The adventure is designed for 5 characters that start at level 1 and should be near level 4 at the end of the adventure.

According to the Player's Handbook the treasure parcels for for such a party should contain:

- 12 magic items

  - 1x level 2
  - 2x level 3
  - 3x level 4
  - 3x level 5
  - 2x level 6
  - 1x level 7
- 3115 gold pieces worth of cash, gems, jewelry, etc., or replaced partially with healing potions

If the players gather all the treasure in all 25 encounters of Keep on the Shadowfell, they gain the following:

- 12 magic items

  - 1x level 1
  - 2x level 2
  - 3x level 3
  - 2x level 4
  - 3x level 5
  - 1x level 6
- 4408 gold pieces worth of cash, gems, jewelry, etc.
- 3 healing potions

So it looks like the magic items awarded are slightly less powerful than the treasure parcels suggest, but the monetary value is roughly 30% higher. Some of this is hidden or in locked chests, but nobody said that treasure hunting would be easy.

Comment: It's a shame that elevenfootpole isn't updating anymore, since I'd have had a very guilty pleasure commenting this on the post mentioned.